# sharepoint navigation manipulation programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a sharepoint website where i have a navigation pane which has all the webparts which are recently used. I need to move the links in the navigation to the archieved folder in the list.

I need help in manipulating the navigation pane. Need someone to help me

Comment: Welcome to SO! Consider adding information about what you've tried / code samples / anything else you think might help to get your issue resolved. As of right now, it's hard to give you any useful advice.